# Recyclerview onBindViewHolder вызывается раньше фильтрации данных

Tags: android, recyclerview, filter, recyclerview.adapter

У моего адаптера RecyclerView есть фильтр, который фильтрует список в соответствии с настройками из преференсов. Проблема в том, что при инициализации списка уже могут быть установлены настройки фильтра, так как в конструктор адаптера я передаю изначально полный список, я так понимаю, что onBindViewHolder вызывается раньше, чем произойдет фильтр списка, в следствие чего у меня возникает IndexOutOfBoundsException, так как OnBindViewHolder начинает выполняться с полным списком, но в процессе выполнения данные изменяются.
Код адаптера

```java
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.EventHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<OptimaEvent> mEvents;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<OptimaEvent> mFilteredEvents;
    private EventFilter mFilter;

    public EventsAdapter(List<OptimaEvent> events, Context context) {
        mEvents = events;
        mFilteredEvents = mEvents;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EventsAdapter.EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        EventItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.event_item, parent, false);
        return new EventsAdapter.EventHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventHolder holder, int position) {
        OptimaEvent event = mFilteredEvents.get(position);
        holder.bind(event);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredEvents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new EventFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class EventFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<OptimaEvent> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (OptimaEvent event : mEvents) {
                    if (AppPreferences.isWarningFilter(mContext)){
                        if (event.getAlertLevel() == 1) {
                            filterList.add(event);
                        }
                    }
                    if (AppPreferences.isInfoFilter(mContext)) {
                        if (event.getAlertLevel() == 0) {
                            filterList.add(event);
                        }
                    }
                    if (event.getAlertLevel() == 2) {
                        filterList.add(event);
                    }
                }
                mFilteredEvents = filterList;
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = mFilteredEvents;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredEvents = (ArrayList<OptimaEvent>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class EventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private EventItemBinding mBinding;

        EventHolder(@NonNull EventItemBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            mBinding = binding;
        }

        void bind(OptimaEvent event) {
            mBinding.setEvent(event);
            mBinding.eventItem.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            });
            mBinding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }

}
```

Фрагмент инициализации RecyclerView.

```java
 @Override
    public void initView(List<OptimaEvent> events) {
        Log.i(TAG, "initView: ");
        mAdapter = new EventsAdapter(events, getContext());
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
        LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        filterAdapter();
        mBinding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mBinding.swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применяйте фильтр к копии списка, и после этот новый список (копию) уже передавайте в адаптер. Не меняйте непосредственно сам список в адаптере, работайте только с его копией.